# Cython: when should I define a string as char*, str, or bytes?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, cython

When defining a variable type that will hold a string in Cython + Python 3, I can use (at least):

```
cdef char* mystring = "foo"
cdef str mystring = "foo"
cdef bytes mystring = "foo"
```

The [documentation page on strings](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/strings.html) is unclear on this -- it mostly gives examples using char* and bytes, and frankly I'm having a lot of difficulty understanding it.

In my case the strings will be coming from a Python3 program and are assumed to be unicode. They will be used as dict keys and function arguments, but I will do no further manipulation on them.  Needless to say I am trying to maximize speed.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23064141/optimizing-strings-in-cython) suggests that under Python2.7 and without Unicode, typing as `str` makes string manipulation code run SLOWER than with no typing at all. (But that's not necessarily relevant here since I won't be doing much string manipulation.)

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each of these options?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If there is no further processing done on a particular type, it would be best and fastest to not type them at all, which means they are treated as a general purpose `PyObject *`.

The `str` type is a [special case](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/strings.html) which means `bytes` on Python 2 and `unicode` on Python 3.

> The str type is special in that it is the byte string in Python 2 and the Unicode string in Python 3

So code that types a string as `str` and handles it as unicode will *break* on python 2 where `str` means `bytes`.

Strings only need to be typed if they are to be converted to C `char*` or C++ `std::string`. There, you would use `str` to handle py2/py3 compatibility, along with helper functions to convert to/from bytes and unicode in order to be able to convert to either `char*` or `std::string`.

Typing of strings is for interoperability with C/C++, not for speed as such. Cython will auto-convert, without copying, a `bytes` string to a `char*` for example when it sees something like `cdef char* c_string = b_string[:b_len]` where `b_string` is a `bytes` type.

OTOH, if strings are typed without that type being used, Cython will do a conversion from object to bytes/unicode when it does not need to which leads to overhead.

This can be seen in the C code generated as `Pyx_PyObject_AsString`, `Pyx_PyUnicode_FromString` et al.

This is also true in general - the rule of thumb is if a specific type is not needed for further processing/conversion, best not to type it at all. Everything in python is an object so typing will convert from the general purpose `PyObject*` to something more specific.

Comment: Wow, that's really helpful. I was under the impression that "if you want to make it go faster, add types to everything!!!" but had no idea it could be more efficient to leave the types off. (if no more processing is being done)

Comment: Glad it was useful. Most speedup gains are in fact from doing away with the python interpreter which Cython gives you out of the box without any static typing. There are still cases where typing is useful, like cdef class attributes to reduce memory footprint and where typing allows Cython to translate to more C code, but need to be aware of what it means and where it is best used. I find looking at the annotated C code to ensure what Cython generated makes sense works well - `cython -a <..>.pyx`. After a while will get used to the obfuscated C code Cython makes.

Answer (score 1):

Some quick testing revealed that for this particular case, only the `str` declaration worked -- all other options produced errors. Since the string is generated elsewhere in Python3, evidently the `str` type declaration is needed.

Whether it is faster not to make any declaration at all remains an open question.